# C++ Quicksort Algorithm Crashing

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am working on a c++ quicksort algorithm that counts the number of significant operations during the sort. It will correctly sort 100 values but after that it gets stuck in an endless loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

//QuickSort.cpp

```
#include "QuickSort.h"
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

QuickSort::QuickSort(int max) : SortData(max)
{
    /*
    maxSize = max;
    theData = new long[max];
    */
    SortData::randomize(12);

}

QuickSort::~QuickSort(void)
{

}

_int64 QuickSort:: sort()
{
    numops = 0;
    quicksort(theData, 0, (size()-1));
    return(numops);
}

//Include counting number of operations
void QuickSort::quicksort(long theData[], int left, int right)
{
    //Default variables

    if (size() <= 1 || left >= size() || right >= size()) return; //Bounds checking

    if (left < right)
    {
        long pivot = partition(theData, left, right);

        quicksort(theData, left, pivot-1);
        quicksort(theData, pivot+1, right);
    }
}

int QuickSort::partition(long theData[], int left, int right)
{
    long pivot = theData[left];
    while (true)
    {
        while (theData[left] < pivot) left++;
        numops ++;

        while (theData[right] > pivot) right--;
        numops ++; 

        if (left < right)
        {
            swap(theData[left], theData[right]);
            numops+=3;
        }

        else
        {
            return right;
        }
    }
}
```

//QuickSort.h

```
#pragma once
#include "SortData.h"

class QuickSort : public SortData
{

public:
    QuickSort(int max = 100);
    ~QuickSort(void);
    _int64 sort();
private:
    _int64 numops;
    void QuickSort::quicksort(long theData[], int left, int right);
    int partition(long theData[], int left, int right);
};
```

Comment: What does SortData look like?  Is it actually allocating an array of size max in the constructor?

Comment: Your `partition` function looks like it will get in an infinite loop if it finds two elements equal to the pivot (I might be mistaken, didn't study your code closely).  If this isn't homework, just use `std::partition`.

Comment: Also note that your `numops` skips a lot of the parition logic.

Comment: Here is a gist for sortdata https://gist.github.com/2771303

Comment: numops should only count the number of significant operations in the sorting.

Answer (score 4):

In you partition function the

```
 if (left < right)
```

is always true. Thus you're getting the infinite while(true) loop.

And there may be a problem in you size() function from the SortData.h which we can not see yet.

Since the data is random you see the problem from time to time on some input sets.

Slight modification must help:

```
if (left <= right) {
         if (left < right) {
             swap(theData[left], theData[right]);
             numops += 3;
         }
         left++;
         right--;
}
else {
    return right;
}
```

Sorry for the double-check :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that condition is fine, since the intent is `left` keeps increasing, and `right` keeps decreasing, and it stops when they meet.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: sth say essentially the same

Answer (score 1):

`partition` gets stuck if `left < right` and `theData[left] == theData[right]`.

Comment: So what would be the easiest way to fix that?

Comment: @user1411112: see my addition for your corner case